# Last 3 Months Where Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, rolling-computation

I've got a SQL statement (SQL Server Management Studio) that I'm passing data into a where-statement into via a dashboard software. The users can select the year (2013 or now 2014) and also the month (which gets passes as a numeric value - so December = 12). I need to adjust the statement to where I get the last 3 months from the year/month they select. Before, b/c the SQL statement was only dealing with 2013 data, it was just the following:

```
YEAR(Main.ActivityDate) = '@Request.parmYear~'
AND (Month(Main.ActivityDate) Between ('@Request.parmMonth~'-2) and '@Request.parmMonth~')
```

Normally, parmYear = 2013 and then whatever month they select, it will grab 2 months prior through the current month.

Now, b/c it's January 2014, I need to to grab January 2014 + December 2013 + November 2013. I'm wondering how to adjust the statement to make this happen dynamically.

Thoughts?

Comment: try using DateAdd function to reduce the number of months

Comment: For the RDBMS you're using, lookup the date functions instead of parsing out year and month just use data math to reduce the 3 monhts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solutions for this.

- Modify your current where statement and add a condition to check for this case.
- Use `DATEADD` function. Present in comments and other answer(s).

**Modifying your where to add Condition**

Note: Minor error may exists since I need to check if January has month value of zero or 1.

Example:

```
WHERE 

(
'@Request.parmMonth~'-2 < 1 AND 
YEAR(Main.ActivityDate) = '@Request.parmYear~'-1 AND
Month(Main.ActivityDate) Between 
(12+'@Request.parmMonth~'-2) AND 12  
)
OR
(
YEAR(Main.ActivityDate) = '@Request.parmYear~'
AND (Month(Main.ActivityDate) Between 
('@Request.parmMonth~'-2) and '@Request.parmMonth~'
)
```

Answer (score 3):

I do not have a running SQL Server instance to test this solution but I would suggest constructing a date and using the built in functions to calculate the previous date as those already take into consideration the multiple years etc.

```
    Declare @requestDate date = DATEFROMPARTS('@Request.parmYear', '@Request.parmMonth', 1);
    ...

    AND Main.ActivityDate between @requestDate AND DATEADD(month, -2, @requestDate )
```

[See this for more](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) details.

Comment: I just realize that this solution has a little mistake. I'll explain it with an example. If the month requested is January 2014, you will obtain the activities between '2014/1/1' and '2013/11/1' but the activities must be between '2014/1/31' and '2013/11/1'.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem some time ago. My solution was something like this:

```
WHERE YEAR(Main.ActivityDate)*12 + YEAR(Month(Main.ActivityDate))
   BETWEEN '@Request.parmYear~'*12+'@Request.parmMonth~'-2 
       AND '@Request.parmYear~'*12+'@Request.parmMonth~'
```

You could improve this solution sending one parameter as the result of `'@Request.parmYear~'*12+'@Request.parmMonth~'`.

Comment: +1 Bravo! Not sure speed wise how this compares with other solutions but ok.

Comment: Thank you! That worked very well and fast for me but actually, when I used it the table was two fields one for month and other for year. I think this case should be worked well too.